# jsf 2.0 redirect to new tab

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, xhtml

I'm trying to redirect to a new tab, this code should be working but it's redirecting me in the same page

xhtml page

```
    <h:form id="previewForm1" target="_blank">
        <p:commandButton value="Preview" action="#{executeJasper.printOnCriteria}" >
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executeJasper.format}" value=".html"/>
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executeJasper.listOnCriteria}" value="#{reports2.exportedWorkOrders}"/>
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{executeJasper.order_by_form}" value="detail_no"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

Bean

```
     try {
                System.out.println("Redirecting....");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(sHandler.getServerURL() + "VAS/faces/Downloads/" + folderName + "\\WorkOrderDetails_" + wOrder + format);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Output File: " + outputFile + " not found");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve redirecting in two ways inside bean you can create a method which you have return type is String and you can return that xhtml page like
 and suppose you want to redirect to test1.xhtml

```
 public String test() {
 //Do some operation
        return test1;

    }
```

The first may be right but you should check the it is proper or not.